# Are my passkeys on my system disk or in the TPM?

Tags: backup, disk-image

Will a system disk-image type backup include my Passkeys created by Windows Hello on Windows 11 23H2?

I'm not yet clear whether they are saved on disk or in the Trusted Platform Module (TPM).
If I restore the image to a disk, will I require my Microsoft password, my local password or my PIN or fingerprint?

I am using the system image backup utility from Windows 7 that is still available under Windows 11. I use it just as a quick way to get my system up and running if my boot disk dies.
File backups are done by Windows File History and BackBlaze.

Comment: PassKeys are not stored in the TPM.  I would not trust those system images for disaster recovery purposes.

Comment: You shouldn't have any passkey/password on the backup, unless you specified it yourself. I note that the Windows 7 Backup is a terrible and untrustworthy product, I would suggest using third-party alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

As I recently learned, it could be either. Run

```
certutil -csp NGC -key -v
```

and look for the value of the `NgcKeyImplType` flag on each key.

See also:

- https://helgeklein.com/blog/checking-windows-hello-for-business-whfb-key-storage-tpm-hardware-or-software/

Comment: Thank you. All of mine were NgcKeyImplType: 1 (0x1), so I guess they are in the TPM. I'm glad I made backup Passkeys on a security key.

Comment: I just realized that the listing for certutil -csp NGC -key -v didn't include any names. I'm not even sure if the listing included my Passkeys or just other sytem lvel certificates.

Comment: That particular CSP is only used by Windows Hello, as far as I know. Other certificates would use a dedicated CSP/KSP for TPM-protected certificates (the 'Platform Key Storage Provider').